# Need String Format Validation in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to validate the given string for a given format.
I have a table as below.

```sql
with t as (
select 'AR' country,8 zip_code_length,'A####AAA' zip_code_format,'B6789CDF' zip_code from dual union all
select 'AR' country,8 zip_code_length,'A####AAA' zip_code_format,'6789CDF' zip_code from dual union all
select 'BR' country,9 zip_code_length,'#####-###' zip_code_format,'12345-678' zip_code from dual union all
select 'BR' country,9 zip_code_length,'#####-###' zip_code_format,'BC345-678' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CA' country,7 zip_code_length,'A#A #A#' zip_code_format,'B2C 8A9' zip_code  from dual union all
select 'CA' country,7 zip_code_length,'A#A #A#' zip_code_format,'BbC CA9' zip_code  from dual union all
select 'CH' country,4 zip_code_length,'####' zip_code_format,'1234' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CH' country,4 zip_code_length,'####' zip_code_format,'123456' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CZ' country,6 zip_code_length,'### ##' zip_code_format,'123 45' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CZ' country,6 zip_code_length,'### ##' zip_code_format,'12345' zip_code from dual union all
select 'EC' country,6 zip_code_length,'A####A' zip_code_format,'B3456C' zip_code from dual union all
select 'EC' country,6 zip_code_length,'A####A' zip_code_format,'BBB56C' zip_code from dual union all
select 'PL' country,6 zip_code_length,'##-###' zip_code_format,'12-345' zip_code from dual union all
select 'PL' country,6 zip_code_length,'##-###' zip_code_format,'12-34567' zip_code from dual
)
select * from t;
```

I have `zip_code_format` and `zip_code` fields in the above query.

I need to validate the `zip_code` against `zip_code_format` field and get `TRUE`/`FALSE` in SQL or PL/SQL.

I would like to have a PL/SQL function where `zip_code` and `zip_code_format` will be the parameters and result would be `TRUE`/`FALSE` in return.

Expected output:

```
country zip_code_length zip_code_format zip_code    validation
AR      8               A####AAA        B6789CDF    TRUE
AR      8               A####AAA        6789CDF     FALSE
BR      9               #####-###       12345-678   TRUE
BR      9               #####-###       BC345-678   FALSE
CA      7               A#A #A#         B2C 8A9     TRUE
CA      7               A#A #A#         BbC CA9     FALSE
CH      4               ####            1234        TRUE
CH      4               ####            123456      FALSE
CZ      6               ### ##          123 45      TRUE
CZ      6               ### ##          12345       FALSE
EC      6               A####A          B3456C      TRUE
EC      6               A####A          BBB56C      FALSE
PL      6               ##-###          12-345      TRUE
PL      6               ##-###          12-34567    FALSE
```

Comment: You need to go read up on [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-1935FD80-A3CD-413F-BD2E-BBEFE64000B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment to MT0's answer but formatting in a comment just does not work so putting this here.  Since the length of the zip_code is supplied, I'd like to suggest doing the more expensive string operations only if the length of the zip_code = the length supplied, otherwise it's automatically false. Note this would allow you better error reporting too, as now you can differentiate between just FALSE in general with FALSE for length didn't match vs FALSE for format didn't match.  Your support folks will thank you.

```
...
CASE 
  WHEN LENGTH(ZIP_CODE) = zip_code_length THEN
    CASE
      WHEN  REGEXP_LIKE(ZIP_CODE,'^'||
            REPLACE(REPLACE(zip_code_format,'#','\d'),'A','[A-Z]')||'$')
        THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'  -- Format didn't match
    END 
  ELSE 'FALSE'  -- Length of zip not correct
END AS VALIDATION
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `#` in the `zip_code_format` with `\d` and `A` with `[A-Z]` and wrap it in `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the strings and then just compare it to the `zip_code` using `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
with t as (
select 'AR' country,8 zip_code_length,'A####AAA' zip_code_format,'B6789CDF' zip_code from dual union all
select 'AR' country,8 zip_code_length,'A####AAA' zip_code_format,'6789CDF' zip_code from dual union all
select 'BR' country,9 zip_code_length,'#####-###' zip_code_format,'12345-678' zip_code from dual union all
select 'BR' country,9 zip_code_length,'#####-###' zip_code_format,'BC345-678' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CA' country,7 zip_code_length,'A#A #A#' zip_code_format,'B2C 8A9' zip_code  from dual union all
select 'CA' country,7 zip_code_length,'A#A #A#' zip_code_format,'BbC CA9' zip_code  from dual union all
select 'CH' country,4 zip_code_length,'####' zip_code_format,'1234' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CH' country,4 zip_code_length,'####' zip_code_format,'123456' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CZ' country,6 zip_code_length,'### ##' zip_code_format,'123 45' zip_code from dual union all
select 'CZ' country,6 zip_code_length,'### ##' zip_code_format,'12345' zip_code from dual union all
select 'EC' country,6 zip_code_length,'A####A' zip_code_format,'B3456C' zip_code from dual union all
select 'EC' country,6 zip_code_length,'A####A' zip_code_format,'BBB56C' zip_code from dual union all
select 'PL' country,6 zip_code_length,'##-###' zip_code_format,'12-345' zip_code from dual union all
select 'PL' country,6 zip_code_length,'##-###' zip_code_format,'12-34567' zip_code from dual
)
SELECT COUNTRY,
       LENGTH( zip_code_format ) AS zip_code_length,
       zip_code_format,
       zip_code,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(
              zip_code,
              '^'
              || REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     zip_code_format,
                     '#',
                     '\d'
                   ),
                   'A',
                   '[A-Z]'
                 )
              || '$'
            )
       THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END AS validation
FROM   t;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> COUNTRY | ZIP_CODE_LENGTH | ZIP_CODE_FORMAT | ZIP_CODE  | VALIDATION
> :------ | --------------: | :-------------- | :-------- | :---------
> AR      |               8 | A####AAA        | B6789CDF  | TRUE      
> AR      |               8 | A####AAA        | 6789CDF   | FALSE     
> BR      |               9 | #####-###       | 12345-678 | TRUE      
> BR      |               9 | #####-###       | BC345-678 | FALSE     
> CA      |               7 | A#A #A#         | B2C 8A9   | TRUE      
> CA      |               7 | A#A #A#         | BbC CA9   | FALSE     
> CH      |               4 | ####            | 1234      | TRUE      
> CH      |               4 | ####            | 123456    | FALSE     
> CZ      |               6 | ### ##          | 123 45    | TRUE      
> CZ      |               6 | ### ##          | 12345     | FALSE     
> EC      |               6 | A####A          | B3456C    | TRUE      
> EC      |               6 | A####A          | BBB56C    | FALSE     
> PL      |               6 | ##-###          | 12-345    | TRUE      
> PL      |               6 | ##-###          | 12-34567  | FALSE
> ```

If you want it in PL/SQL then just do exactly the same inside a function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION validate_zip_code(
  in_zip_code        IN VARCHAR2,
  in_zip_code_format IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(
       in_zip_code,
       '^'
       || REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           in_zip_code_format,
           '#',
           '\d'
         ),
         'A',
         '[A-Z]'
       )
       || '$'
     )
  THEN RETURN 'TRUE';
  ELSE RETURN 'FALSE';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then, for the same data:

```sql
SELECT COUNTRY,
       LENGTH( zip_code_format ) AS zip_code_length,
       zip_code_format,
       zip_code,
       validate_zip_code( zip_code, zip_code_format ) AS validation
FROM   t;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COUNTRY | ZIP_CODE_LENGTH | ZIP_CODE_FORMAT | ZIP_CODE  | VALIDATION
> :------ | --------------: | :-------------- | :-------- | :---------
> AR      |               8 | A####AAA        | B6789CDF  | TRUE      
> AR      |               8 | A####AAA        | 6789CDF   | FALSE     
> BR      |               9 | #####-###       | 12345-678 | TRUE      
> BR      |               9 | #####-###       | BC345-678 | FALSE     
> CA      |               7 | A#A #A#         | B2C 8A9   | TRUE      
> CA      |               7 | A#A #A#         | BbC CA9   | FALSE     
> CH      |               4 | ####            | 1234      | TRUE      
> CH      |               4 | ####            | 123456    | FALSE     
> CZ      |               6 | ### ##          | 123 45    | TRUE      
> CZ      |               6 | ### ##          | 12345     | FALSE     
> EC      |               6 | A####A          | B3456C    | TRUE      
> EC      |               6 | A####A          | BBB56C    | FALSE     
> PL      |               6 | ##-###          | 12-345    | TRUE      
> PL      |               6 | ##-###          | 12-34567  | FALSE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=19ddb8584e8c0bfcb4218726ead7c5bc)*

Comment: @MTO, looks like a good suggestion. I will test and get back to you. Thanks